# FactoryGirl Rails: how to properly define Aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'm trying to define a aliases to an existing factory, but its giving me an error: `undefined method author= for #<Post:0x7217bc8>`

**FactoryGirl definition**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user, aliases: [:author] do |f|
    f.username { "Banana" }
    f.email { "Ilovebanana" }
  end

  factory :post do |p|
    author
    p.title { "Monkey" }
    p.content { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2) }
  end
end
```

The two model has an association of User has_many :posts and Post belongs_to :user

**Test ran:**

```
it "should be valid" do
    post = build(:post)
    post.should be_valid
 end
```

Any suggestion why it's giving me that error? im following this [guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) here

Answer (score 1):

It seems like in the guide `Post` model does have `author` association.
It is more natural for a post to have a `author` rather than a `user`.
So in the guide `Post` does have `author` method I think.

You can edit your `user` association to `author` in `Post` model like

```
belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

or change you `post` factory to something like this

```
factory :post do
  association :user, factory: :author # or user { create :author }
  title   "Monkey"
  content Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2)
end
```

Also notice that you don't need to use block to set primitive values to the fields such as `title` or `content`